# Unit test Web Api 2 set cookie value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

In my api controller I access the cookie value  :

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    protected int? GetUserFromCookie()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["User"] != null)
        {
            //do something
        }
     }
}
```

I create unit test for that and try to do something like:

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://stackoverflow/", "");
var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);
HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
```

But the `HttpContext.Current` is still empty. 
Any idea about this ?

Comment: Do you setup your fake HttpContext in Initialize ?

Comment: yes , i tried also in Initialize class , but nothing..

Comment: Can you please create a sample [TestClass] reproducing your problem and paste here ?

Comment: I'm not sure we should use `HttpContext.Current.Request` for Web API (see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies)